# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: machine-learning, flask, pickle, sentiment-analysis, joblib

I am trying to pass a tweet from a flask UI and be able to make a prediction of the type of the tweet if its a donation, disaster etc.

Here is a working code from Jupyter notebook:

```
loaded_model = joblib.load('NB_spam_model.pkl')
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, y_test)
predict = loaded_model.predict([new_tweet])
print(result)
print(predict)
```

The results

```
0.8409090909090909
['donations_and_help']
```

May someone help me look at the code and correct me where i am doing it wrong?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html" )

@app.route("/predict", methods=["GET","POST"])
def api():



if request.method == "POST":
        words = joblib.load('words.pkl')
        model = joblib.load('NB_spam_model.pkl')
        pstem = PorterStemmer()

        tweet = request.form["tweet"]
        text = tweet
        text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', text)   
        text = text.lower()
        text = text.split()
        text = [pstem.stem(word) for word in text if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
        text = ' '.join(text)
        print("This is the text %s:" + text)

        query = []
        for word in words:
            if word in text:
                query.append(1)
            else:
                query.append(0)

        print(query)
        #prediction = list(model.predict(np.matrix(query)))[0]
        pred = model.predict(query)[0]

        print(pred)

        if pred == 1:
            msg = "."
            return render_template("index.html", msg=msg, tweet=tweet)
        else:
            error = "Approximately 70%, your tweet Fake"
            return render_template("index.html", error=error, tweet=tweet)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Stack trace:

```
Project\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", 
   line 69, in _preprocess
   doc = doc.lower()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2020 20:17:47] "?[35m?[1mPOST /predict HTTP/1.1?[0m" 500 -
```

Answer (score 2):

As you see the error is AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower' which means integer cannot be lower-cased. Somewhere in your code, it tries to lower case integer object which is not possible
First check your text value using `print(text)` before converting to lower

Comment: Hi @Ritik Kumar i checked the text, it still will be text before passing it to the model

Comment: Hello @omah94..can you tell what's value of text here  (and upvote my answer if it is little bit useful :''!)

Comment: for example if the user inputs "My donation" on the form the output for print(text)  would be donat

Comment: Oh..actually I'm not that much familiar with api's. I just gave the answer from python point of  view